# "react-hook-form" with disabled input returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

In my React app, I have a form with a couple of input fields. I wrap the fields with FormProvider imported from react-hook-form and use register in the fields

```
import { useForm, FormProvider, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
```

Now one of the input field is disabled and on Submit, I do not see the input value for this disabled input box.
How can I fix this and get the disabled form input ?

Answer (score 3):

Please use readonly because disable input will not return value after form submit.

Comment: Actually I have a customized Form wrapper, which renders a label for a readonly field, but I want instead a disabled input box to be rendered....So was thinking if I would be able to read the value with "disabled"

Comment: Hello,

Here some confusion so please clear this thing,

Do you need to save data in database or just you want see in fronted without editing?

Comment: So for a disabled input, I want to render as disabled and on submit, I need the value (though in this case, I might just resubmit the same disabled value to the backend)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value to the relevant field in useForm()

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm({
    values: {
      name: "Elvin",
      age: 29,
    },
  });
```

then, you can use `disabled` attribute and get the field value

```
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Name"
      {...register("name")}
      disabled
     />
```